# Read in values from a text file and output certain values

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, scripting

I am working out some custom backup scripts and the last bit I want to do has me stumped.

Searched through the posts and didn't quite find a solution to what I am trying to do.

I need to read in the values form a text file that is the result of this command which is creating a list of every ZIP file in the activebackup dir along with its size

```
forfiles /p f:\activebackup /s /m *ZIP /c "cmd /c echo @fname @fsize" > c:\scripts\output\filesize.txt
```

Output is pretty much:

```
server_name1-date.zip 23454623 
server_name2-date.zip 7862457 
server_name3-date.zip 22 
server_name4-date.zip 98 
etc
```

I need to read in all of the entries (For loop?) and output only the lines that are size 100 or less. Then be able to use the output as a variable so the variable (based on the date above) would be server_name3-date.zip 22, server_name4-date.zip 98.

This way I can use the variable in a job that generates an existing email with an added line like:

```
echo The following ZIPs are too small: %value_too_small%
```

Thanks for any guidance and examples in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Give this a test.  Batch math fails over 2gb sizes but it might work for lower sizes.

```
forfiles /p f:\activebackup /s /m *ZIP /c "cmd /c if @fsize LEQ 100 echo @fname @fsize" > c:\scripts\output\filesize.txt
```

Comment: +1, Large file sizes will work just fine because within an IF comparison, numbers larger than 2147483647 are treated as equal to 2147483647, which of course is greater than 100. See [Rules for how CMD.EXE parses numbers](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3758)

Answer (score 0):

FORFILES can be used, but it is very slow. It is much faster to use a simple FOR loop with the /R option. The `~z` modifier provides the file size.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "tooSmall="
for /r "f:\activebackup" %%F in (*.zip) do if %%~zF leq 100 set "tooSmall=!tooSmall!"%%~fF", "
set "tooSmall=!tooSmall:~0,-2!"
```

The code above will fail if a file path contains `!` because delayed expansion is enabled when the FOR loop is expanded. There are work-arounds if necessary.

Also, remember that environment variables are limited to ~8191 bytes long. If it is possible that you may have many files such that the max length is exceeded, then you will have to come up with a way of composing your email one file at a time.